# Map key - values in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have the following case in typescript:

```
type RecordKeys = 1 | 2 | 3
type RecordValues = "one" | "two" | "three"

function test(param: RecordKeys ): RecordValues {
  switch(param) {
    case(1): {
      return 'one'
    }
    case(2): {
      return 'two'
    }
    case(3): {
      return "three"
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way to correctly type this function to ensure that what is returned from this function corresponds to an actual map? For example :
if param = 1 then "one" will be returned
if param = 2 then "two" will be returned and so on.

Comment: Yes, you can type this properly using function overloads. With that said, Is it not [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Seems you're re-implementing maps or maybe even an enum. And even if the usage does make sense in the real context, are you *sure* you need *the exact type* as a result from this? Not just `RecordValues`? Because I'm pretty sure that you shouldn't need the result being `"two"` if you need to also handle `"three"` anyway.

Comment: BTW, the return values don't align to `RecordValues`. It seems like a transcribing error but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Vlaz, I don't think this is an XY problem, as polluting the question with unnecessary information won't help, as the core content of the question is summarised on what I have posted above.  It seems that function overloads as you suggested provides me with the solution I was looking for. So thanks for this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a hashmap, here's an example:

```
const testMap: Record<number, string> = {
    1: 'one',
    2: 'two',
    3: 'three'
}

// use the hashmap to get the value
function test2(param: number): String {
    return testMap[param]
}
```

Comment: You can improve type-safety by adding the Record utility type to testMap like this: `const testMap: Record<number, string> = { /* key: value */ }`

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question, though.

Answer (score 1):

For clarity, I'm posting an implementation of what @Vlaz suggested above with function overloads.

```
type RecordKeys = 1 | 2 | 3

function test(param: 1): "one" 
function test(param: 2): "two" 
function test(param: 3): "three" 

function test(param: RecordKeys) {
  switch(param){
    case(1): {
      return "one"
    }
    case(2): {
      return "two"
    }
    case(3): {
      return "three"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make `test` a generic function parameterized by key type and then rely on type inference:

```
type Rec = {
  1: "one",
  2: "two",
  3: "three",
}

const rec: Rec = {
  1: "one",
  2: "two",
  3: "three",
}

function test<K extends keyof Rec>(param: K): Rec[K] {
  return rec[param]
}

const x = test(1) // typeof x === "one"
const y = test(2) // typeof y === "two"
const z = test(3) // typeof y === "three"

const fail = test(4) // Argument of type '4' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof Rec'
const fail2: 'two' = test(3) // Type '"three"' is not assignable to type "two"
```

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4&ssl=22&ssc=29&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDGUC8UDeAoKUCMAuKARAPYB2EBANJlAEz4HADuRl1AzPcABYBOE5VAL7p08UgGdgUPvHxxEKDFjyFSA6nUJMWVLBy29+rYegBmAVxLxgAS1JRgESQB4A0lAgAPRyQAm4qABrCBAiU1gEAD4ACjAAQx44gFt8VwBKOQQAbVcAXTRqPmBzHhJpbPjEpNz0EzESSShPZAcnYGjsNKgAem6HcAgwpuQkFGIyAlEJKRAWx0lomi7e-sgh2dGx7Un6xoAvObbotmW+0DXwjdGDPnIRXalTOJsAG0OFgBY0qYbH55fNABybSA97tE5AA)